# Is there ever going to be a Typescript `mixin` keyword?

Tags: typescript

I have been reading about mixins in Typescript, trying to find a better composition method than class extension.  I've gotten some pretty cool stuff working.  But I'm always creating functions that look like this:

```
export function CanFly<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base {
        flying: boolean;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
        }
        fly () {
            this.flying = true;
        }
        land () {
            this.flying = false;
        }
    };
}
class Person {
    name: string;
}
export class SuperHero extends CanFly(Person) {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }
}
```

It seems like there should be a mixin keyword or something to remove the cruft of: `<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T)`.  Does such a thing exist?

In C# you can just extend multiple classes which seems to accomplish something quite similar.  Is that the direction things are going?  Or will there be a mixin keyword in the future?

Comment: In C# you can't extend multiple classes. You can implement multiple interfaces...